# Why doesn't Rust support overloading function or method?

Tags: rust

Method overloading in java is a very helpful feature. Sometimes, we need define functions with the same name but with different set of arguments. I'm wondering why rust does not support this feature.

Comment: You never *need* to define a function with the same name in Java, you *choose* to.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In C++, you some time _need_ to use the same name, since you want to use the function in a template for a generic type. This argument does not apply to Rust though.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236166/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-function-with-different-numbers-of-arguments-using) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936872/how-do-i-use-parameter-overloading-or-optional-parameters-in-rust) of interest.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, which is why I specified Java. C++ use of overloads for templates is covered by Rust use of traits for generics. Since the OP mentioned Java and not C++, though, I didn't want to muddy the waters.

Comment: The answer to your question is: Rust is a system level programming language, which means, putting it in simple terms, that symbols you define in your code are passed verbatim to the link phase. In Java, Scala and several other languages, the compiler actually does some trickery behind the scenes, changing the actual names of your symbols, so that they do not clash with one another. This way, when you define several constructors for your classes in Java, the compiler actually creates multiple constructors with distinct names behind the scenes for you.

Comment: @RichardGomes This is not true. First, C++ also is a systems programming language, and it does support function overloading. Second, Rust mangles names before linking, just as C++ does. You can easily see the mangled names with `objdump` or `nm`.

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that in some way Rust *does* have function and method overloading.

Let's say you want to implement an `abs()` function that can either take an integer or a floating-point number. In C++, you could use

```cpp
int abs(int x) { ... }
double abs(double x) { ... }
```

This will allow to call `abs()` with either an `int` or a `double` as an argument, and the compiler will choose the right implementation for you.

In Rust, you use traits instead. Traits can be implemented on foreign types including standarad types, so this is an adequate replacement:

```
trait Abs {
    fn abs(self) -> Self;
}

impl Abs for i32 {
    fn abs(self) -> Self { ... }
}

impl Abs for f32 {
    fn abs(self) -> Self { ... }
}
```

This will allow you to call `x.abs()`, where `x` is either an `i32` or an `f32`, and the compiler will choose the right implementation for you.

You are not even limited to having the compiler base the decision on the method receiver alone. If you define a trait parametrized by a type, the compiler will choose the method implementation based on the type of additional parameters:

```
trait Trait<T> {
    fn foo(&self, x: T);
}

struct Bar;

impl Trait<i32> for Bar {
    fn foo(&self, _: i32) {
        println!("i32");
    }
}

impl Trait<u32> for Bar {
    fn foo(&self, _: u32) {
        println!("u32");
    }
}

fn main() {
    Bar.foo(1i32);  // prints "i32"
    Bar.foo(1u32);  // prints "u32"
}
```

Comment: what about overloads with varying amount of arguments?

Comment: @JFFIGK That's not really possible. You can have identically named functions on different traits, but the compiler won't automatically pick the right one for you – you need to use fully qualified syntax to pick the function you want. And macros can be variadic, so maybe that's an option for your use case.

Comment: "I would argue that in some way Rust does have function ... overloading." You showed non-variadic instance MEMBER function overloading, but not static member function overloading nor free function overloading. This "generic" business simply doesn't count.

Comment: @lmat Rust does not have member functions or static member functions, because it's not an object-oriented language. In any case, the approach in this answer can be trivially extended to one-argument free functions and associated functions without a receiver. It doesn't work for functions with multiple arguments, so I guess it also "simply doesn't count".

Comment: Rust does not provide function overloading. Rust does not provide method overloading.
You are not answering the question. The question is about "why"... not about "how" you would try to circumvent.

Comment: @RichardGomes I think this answer is useful in the context of this question, since it shows two ways of solving the same that function overloading solves, at least in some common cases. I could instead speculate (or fantasize) about the reasons of the design decision not to have function overloading, but I don't think this would have much practical benefit. I usually want to help the OP when answering a question, but I also want to help later visitors who come here via their search engine. If you don't think it's helpful, fair enough, I'm ok with that.